# Build a div class to remove sticky element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a simple piece of Javascript that sticks a header on scroll past

```
<div id="left">hello world</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(stickyRelocate);
});

var left = document.getElementById("left");
var stop = (left.offsetTop - 60);

window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    console.log(scrollTop, left.offsetTop);

    if (scrollTop >= stop) {
        left.className = 'stick';
    } else {
        left.className = '';
    }
}
```

I need to build a new class

```
<div="remove-stick"></div>
```

And have the sticky removed after scroll past.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to add new element for removing existing one??

Comment: as i only want this element sticky for a number of sections

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
left. removeAttribute('stick');
```

Comment: and name the class remove-stick ?    left. removeAttribute('remove-stick');